# Calculating an integral using the limit definition

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-sum

**"$f\left(x\right)=-\frac{x^2}{3}-2$**

**We are supposed to calculate $\int _0^2\:\left(-\frac{x^2}{3}-2\right)dx$ using the limit definition of an integral.**

**a) Calculate $Rn$ for $f(x)$, which is the Riemann sum where the sample points are chosen to be right-hand endpoints of each sub-interval on the interval [0,2]. Write your answer as a function of n without summation signs.**

**b) Calculate the limit of Rn as n approaches infinity."**

I think the main confusion I am having is with part a. How exactly am I supposed to find the Riemann sum without knowing the length of each sub-interval? Am I supposed to make each sub-interval $1/n$ and then keep going until $2n/n$. As these would be the right endpoints?  If so, how would I calculate the sum of these seemingly infinite amount of intervals? Or am I supposed to approach this problem in a different way?

Any help?

Comment: Start with a finite number of points in $[0,2]$, and if you like they can be at the same distance i.e. $\frac 1n$ from each other, and these would be correct endpoints. For this finite partition, you will get a Riemann sum, which will clearly depend on $n$. Let $n \to \infty$,(so there is no infinite sum involved, really) and the result is the desired integral.

Comment: The  length of a subinterval is $\frac{b-a}{n}$ which is precisely the step $\Delta x$, so the first interval is $(a,a+\Delta x)$, the right hand end point is $a+\Delta x$ so the first rectangle has area $f(a+\Delta x)\Delta x$